# Xargs, sqlplus and quote nightmare?

Tags: sql, bash, shell, sqlplus, xargs

**I have one big file containing data, for example :**

```
123;test/x/COD_ACT_008510/descr="R08-Ballon d''eau"
456;test/x/COD_ACT_008510/descr="R08-Ballon d''eau"
```

In reality, there is much more column but I simplified here.
I want to treat each line, and do some sqlplus treatment with them.
**Let say that I have one table, with two column, with this :**

```
ID  | CONTENT
123 | test/x/COD_ACT_333/descr="Test 1"
456 | test/x/COD_ACT_444/descr="Test 2"
```

**Let say I want to update the two lines content value to have that :**

```
ID  | CONTENT
123 | test/x/COD_ACT_008510/descr="R08-Ballon d''eau"
456 | test/x/COD_ACT_008510/descr="R08-Ballon d''eau"
```

I have a lot of data and complex request to execute in reality, so I have to use sqlplus, not tools like sqlloader.

So, I treat the input file on 5 multi thread, one line at each time, and define "\n" like separator to evict quote conflict :

```
cat input_file.txt | xargs -n 1 -P 5 -d '\n' ./my_script.sh &
```

**In "my_script.sh" I have :**

```
#!/bin/bash

line="$1"

sim_id=$(echo "$line" | cut -d';' -f1)
content=$(echo "$line" | cut -d';' -f2)

sqlplus -s $DBUSER/$DBPASSWORD@$DBHOST:$DBPORT/$DBSCHEMA @updateRequest.sql "$id" "'"$content"'"
```

**And in the updateRequest.sql file (just containing a test) :**

```
set heading off
set feed off
set pages 0
set verify off

update T_TABLE SET CONTENT = '&2' where ID = '&1';
commit;
```

**And in result, I have :**

```
01740: missing double quote in identifier
If I put “verify” parameter to on in the sql script, I can see : 
old   1: select '&2' from dual
new   1: select 'test/BVAL/COD_ACT_008510/descr="R08-Ballon d'eau"' from dual
```

It seems like one of the two single quotes (used for escape the second quote) is missing...

I tried everything, but each time I have an error with quote or double quote, either of bash side, or sql side... it's endless :/

I need the double quote for the "descr" part, and I need to process the apostrophe (quote) in content.
For info, the input file is generated automatically, but I can modify his format.

Comment: You have to quote `$content` to avoid splitting on spaces, and you have to escape the `'`s again because sqlplus removes one layer of escaping. Where does `select '&3' from dual` come from?

Comment: It was a mistake, I edit my original post, it’s “&2”, it’s the sqlplus verify log which display the request before and after replacing the parameter in request. I already quote content, what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Seems to work replacing quote by four quote (two time escape).

Comment: A well defined problem and glad you found a (complex/brittle) solution, but ... ouch, can't you create a tmp table and update between the tmp and your main table based on your ID column? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
dburl=oracle://$DBUSER:$DBPASSWORD@$DBHOST:$DBPORT/$DBSCHEMA
cat big |
  parallel -j5 -v --colsep ';' -q sql $dburl "update T_TABLE SET CONTENT = '{=2 s/'/''/g=}' where ID = '{1}'; commit;"
```

But only if you do not have ; in the values. So given this input it will do the wrong thing:

```
456;test/x/COD_ACT_008510/descr="semicolon;in;value"
```